# why the execute sql changed when process running with mybatis and postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

Today I encount an wired problem, the execute sql changed when repeat request to PostgreSQL 13, this is my mybatis mapper xml define:

```
  <select id="getArticleIds" resultMap="ArticleIds">
    select
    id as id
    from article
    <trim prefix="WHERE" prefixOverrides="AND|OR">
      <if test="request.endDate != null">
        and created_time &lt; #{request.endDate,jdbcType=BIGINT}
      </if>
      <if test="request.startDate != null">
        and created_time &gt; #{request.startDate,jdbcType=BIGINT}
      </if>
    </trim>
    order by created_time desc limit 3000
  </select>
```

when execute this request again and again, the server shows the error log like this:

```
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-1] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@737aa1dc]
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-2] - Creating a new SqlSession
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-2] - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@6207e923] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-2] - JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1032688854 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1d30004c] will not be managed by Spring
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-2] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT id AS id FROM article ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 3000
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-2] - ==> Parameters:
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-2] - <==      Total: 3000
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-2] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@6207e923]
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-4] - Creating a new SqlSession
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-4] - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@7a3d1167] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-4] - JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1837646083 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1d30004c] will not be managed by Spring
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-4] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT count(0) FROM article LIMIT 3000
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-4] - ==> Parameters:
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-4] - <==      Total: 1
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-4] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT id AS id FROM article LIMIT 3000 ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT ?
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-4] - ==> Parameters: 10(Integer)
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-4] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@7a3d1167]
2021-04-25 11:19:01.081 ERROR 29853 --- [io-11014-exec-4] m.s.advice.ControllerResponseAdvice      : (SERVICE EXCEPTION - SC: 500, RC: 500) -> 

misc.exception.ServiceException: 
    at misc.exception.ServiceException.wrapServiceException(ServiceException.java:147) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at misc.exception.ServiceException.wrapServiceException(ServiceException.java:141) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at misc.exception.ServiceException.getHandleException(ServiceException.java:259) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at misc.spring.advice.ControllerResponseAdvice.handleException(ControllerResponseAdvice.java:92) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:409) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:61) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1299) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1111) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:97) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:151) ~[spring-session-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:86) ~[spring-session-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.12.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ORDER"
  Position: 41
### The error may exist in class path resource [mybatis/mapper/dolphin/CustomArticleMapper.xml]
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT id AS id FROM article LIMIT 3000 ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT ?
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ORDER"
  Position: 41
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ORDER"
  Position: 41
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:88) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:440) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:223) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:85) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.getArticleIds(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.article.ArticleService.getInitialArticleIds(ArticleService.java:120) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.article.ArticleService.getArticleImpl(ArticleService.java:102) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.service.impl.article.ArticleService.pageEnhance(ArticleService.java:70) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.ArticleController.originalStories(ArticleController.java:98) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.ArticleController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$970cb5ae.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.controller.impl.ArticleController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a759a5ed.originalStories(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ORDER"
  Position: 41
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2505) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar!/:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2241) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar!/:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar!/:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar!/:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:368) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar!/:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:158) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar!/:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:147) ~[postgresql-42.2.9.jar!/:42.2.9]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor207.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:59) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy185.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:64) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy183.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.github.pagehelper.util.ExecutorUtil.pageQuery(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[pagehelper-5.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor.intercept(PageInterceptor.java:107) ~[pagehelper-5.2.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:49) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at tk.mybatis.orderbyhelper.OrderByHelper.intercept(OrderByHelper.java:115) ~[orderby-helper-0.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140) ~[mybatis-3.5.5.jar!/:3.5.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.5.jar!/:2.0.5]
    ... 78 common frames omitted

DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-3] - Creating a new SqlSession
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-3] - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3eec24b4] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-3] - JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@136681552 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1d30004c] will not be managed by Spring
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-3] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT count(0) FROM article LIMIT 3000
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-3] - ==> Parameters:
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-3] - <==      Total: 1
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-3] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT id AS id FROM article LIMIT 3000 ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT ?
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-3] - ==> Parameters: 10(Integer)
DEBUG [http-nio-11014-exec-3] - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3eec24b4]
2021-04-25 11:19:01.351 ERROR 29853 --- [io-11014-exec-3]
```

according the log, the sql works fine but finnally, it changed to a bad grammer sql command, why  would this happen? what should I do to fix it?

Comment: MyBatis does not rewrite SQL by itself. There is `tk.mybatis.orderbyhelper.OrderByHelper` in the stack trace, so you may be using this [plugin](https://github.com/abel533/OrderByHelper) and it rewrites the query, probably.

Comment: I fail to see where the SQL `SELECT id AS id FROM article LIMIT 3000 ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT ?` comes from. The mapper you are showing does not produce that SQL. Must be a different mapper.

Comment: Sounds like @ave may be right. I don't know that library but looks like it acts as an advice that tweaks the SQL. It's in version 0.0.2 (doesn't sound suitable for production) so I would suggest you disable/remove it.

Comment: It is wired, I think the lib maybe have problem. I will think to replace it with another lib. @TheImpaler

Comment: The SQL maybe changed by some interceptor. @TheImpaler

Comment: @Dolphin Yes, that's what I meant by "advice". The guess is that the `OrderByHelper` is acting as an AOP advice.